# Add UISearchBar on UICollectionViewController Header

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, uisearchbar, uicollectionview

Hi, I want to add a search option at the top of `UICollectionViewController`. I tried some codes from here but its not working for me.

What I've done so far is:

1. Created one `UICollectioViewController`
2. Then checked check box for the header
3. Add a `UITextfield` to the header row
4. Created a `UICollectionViewReusablecell`, then declared my `UISearchBar` there.

But I don't know how to take the value from that `UITextfield` and check with the values in my array "All Details" and display the results in tableview?

Currently in `UICollectionViewCell` I am using this code for taking the text entering to `UITextField`:

```
[searchTextfield addTarget:self action:@selector(check:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Please check this link below. I didn't understand this, maybe you can help me

```
http://www.appcoda.com/supplementary-view-uicollectionview-flow-layout/
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the links below with the sample codes in Github. You can download and integrate UICollectionView With UISearchBar using these links.

https://maniacdev.com/2015/01/example-how-to-integrate-uicollectionview-with-uisearchbar

[Searching and filtering cells in a UICollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119738/searching-and-filtering-cells-in-a-uicollectionview)