# Searching and filtering cells in a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, filter, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` with a bunch of cells, and so there are two things I want accomplish with this view.

First, I want to have a search bar at the top that will be able to filter the cells according to the users' query. I have only seen search bar implemented with `UITableView`, so how would I go about doing this?

Also, I would like to have a button called "Filters," that when clicked, would show a pop-up view controller with a series of checkboxes along with their values. So if I user selects the check box, it will filter the cells according to their checks once the user presses the "Done" button, which would be located at the top right corner. There would also be a "Cancel" button at the top left if the user doesn't decide to filter his search.

A picture of my `UICollectionView`:

[image: UICollectionview]

**MY CODE**

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
    backpackIcons *item = _backpackItems[indexPath.row];
    NSString *photoURL = item.image_url;
    NSString *quality = item.quality;
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *itemImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    itemImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:photoURL]]];
    [itemImageView setBackgroundColor:Rgb2UIColor(60, 53, 46)];
    if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", quality] isEqualToString:@"6"])
    {
        [itemImageView.layer setBorderColor:[Rgb2UIColor(125, 109, 0) CGColor]];
    }
    else if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", quality] isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        [itemImageView.layer setBorderColor:[Rgb2UIColor(77, 116, 85) CGColor]];
    }
    else if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", quality] isEqualToString:@"3"])
    {
        [itemImageView.layer setBorderColor:[Rgb2UIColor(71, 98, 145) CGColor]];
    }
    else if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", quality] isEqualToString:@"5"])
    {
        [itemImageView.layer setBorderColor:[Rgb2UIColor(134, 80, 172) CGColor]];
    }
    else if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", quality] isEqualToString:@"11"])
    {
        [itemImageView.layer setBorderColor:[Rgb2UIColor(207, 106, 50) CGColor]];
    }
    else if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", quality] isEqualToString:@"7"] || [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", quality] isEqualToString:@"9"])
    {
        [itemImageView.layer setBorderColor:[Rgb2UIColor(112, 176, 74) CGColor]];
    }
    else if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", quality] isEqualToString:@"8"])
    {
        [itemImageView.layer setBorderColor:[Rgb2UIColor(165, 15, 121) CGColor]];
    }
    else if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", quality] isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
        [itemImageView.layer setBorderColor:[Rgb2UIColor(178, 178, 178) CGColor]];
    }
    else if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", quality] isEqualToString:@"13"])
    {
        [itemImageView.layer setBorderColor:[Rgb2UIColor(56, 243, 171) CGColor]];
    }
    else
    {
        [itemImageView.layer setBorderColor:[Rgb2UIColor(170, 0, 0) CGColor]];
    }
        [itemImageView.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Not relevant to the actual question you asked, but I would suggest reading `quality` into an `int` value before all your `if/else` statements so you don't have to keep comparing string values. (e.g. `int qualityValue = [quality intValue];` You could even use a `switch` statement to speed things up further.

Comment: @Stonz2 thanks for the idea. We altered the code so it runs much more quickly.

Answer (score 4):

I've hacked a simple example of searching and filtering the `UICollectionView`, you can download the code here: https://github.com/kambala-decapitator/uicollectionview-search-filter.

I decided to add the search bar to navigation bar, but you're free to add it as a subview to collection view (and adjust `contentOffset` property if needed) or simply to view controller's view. Also, maybe you'd want to show Filters as a simple modal view controller, which is a bit easier from the coding point of view :)

Note that in real code you should subclass UICollectionViewCell and not use `subviews` hack like I do :)

[timothykc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1758337/timothykc) has already provided some implementation basics. Feel free to ask if something is unclear.

Comment: would I use a uisearchbar or a search bar with display controller

Comment: `UISearchDisplayController` relies on `UITableView` (it displays search results there), so I don't think it's the way to go in your case.

Comment: Hi kambala. Thanks for the answer. If I have any more questions can I ask here?

Comment: sure you can, why not

Comment: how would I be able to tag the cells with multiple values. Like, I want to filter the cells by specific categories, not just by their name.

Comment: you filter your model objects (data source), not the cells themselves. So after selecting filters, you apply them to your model, create new data source array and reload the table.

Comment: Thanks, also, another question. How would I be able to load the filters view controller modally? Do I just connect a modal segue?

Comment: yes, if you're using storyboard (or call `presentViewController:...` manually from code otherwise). In such case don't use custom animation and adding view controller as a child, like in my example.

Comment: Hi kambala. I have implemented your search bar but I cannot get it to work. The problem I'm having is that I'm asynchronously loading the uicollectionview cells now in order to make them appear faster and not laggy (there are 300+ cells). Could you join my chat room so we can discuss? Thanks. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57668/uicollectionview-searchbar-error

Comment: hey could you join my chat again? I have a problem closing my modal segue. It comes up, but I cannot seem to close it.  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57910/uiviewcontroller-not-closing-from-modal-segue

Answer (score 2):

First, it's important to think of the "search bar" as a filter **for the array** used to populate the collection view. Once you conceptualize it that way, then it's a simply a question of how sophisticated/intelligent you want to make your filter operation.

In broad strokes you can simply add the search bar in IB, and then click drag it to the view controller. (do the same with your "filter buttons" -- but make them IB actions.)

So the Viewcontroller.h in question should conform to both UISearchDisplayDelegate/UIsearchbardelegate

In the .m file, you add the method

```
searchBar:(UISearchBar *)bar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
```

Here, there should be the logic to tweak the nsmutablearray that contains all the "items" that are populated into the collection view. An easy logic is to filter objects out of the array by letters you type, and then repopulate the array the collection view relies upon based on that. Then, you force the collection view to reload so that collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection: and collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: draw from the "filtered" array.

For the buttons, you likewise force some logic upon the array copy (predefined as you choose) and reload the collectionview.

Comment: Again, thanks for the answer. If I have any more questions can I ask here?

Comment: I'll be on intermittently (work and family :), but sure, if I can provide some guidance I'll be happy to.

Comment: I have a problem with implementing the search bar in my uicollectionview. Could you please join my chat room to help me? thanks. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57668/uicollectionview-searchbar-error

Comment: Could you please see my new question? Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874242/array-objectatindex-out-of-bounds-error

Comment: Could you please see my new question? Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874242/array-objectatindex-out-of-bounds-error

Comment: I'm in the middle of a release deadline, but once I've got a little more bandwidth, I'll take a look again.

Answer (score 1):

All these projects were so needlessly complicated that I ended up writing one on my own. Check it out here at github: https://github.com/sambudda/UICollectionViewWithSearchBar

If you love the simplicity of it then please rate it up.

Answer (score 0):

Two months ago, I built an example of how to use UISearchBar with a UICollectionViewController easily, with proper filtering and searching.

I implemented KVO, UISearchBarDelegate, and UICollectionViewDelegate to achieve a good result. Today I updated it to add support UIRefreshControl.

Check it out here: https://github.com/ihomam/CollectionViewWithSearchBar