# How to implement search bar in uicollectionview in iOS?

Tags: ios, ipad, uicollectionview, uisearchbar

I want to put search facility in collection view in iPad. I have done this in tableview but how to do it in collection view?

Comment: please have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119738/searching-and-filtering-cells-in-a-uicollectionview/24598463#24598463

Answer (score 0):

**UICollectionViewLayout class**

Supplementary views present data but are different than cells. Unlike cells, supplementary views cannot be selected by the user. Instead, you use supplementary views to implement things like header and footer views for a given section or for the entire collection view. Supplementary views are optional and their use and placement is defined by the layout object

**EDIT**

More information about using supplementary views: [Creating Custom Layouts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html)

Comment: can you please provide me an example for that ?